# mysql recursive bom sample

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion

I'm trying to find multilevel bom records. You can find sample table here : https://dbfiddle.uk/aTw3DJr2

thanks to Bill Karwin, my updated query as below.

```
    with recursive boms as 
    (select material,component,quantity 
    from iasbomitem 
    where material='blue_ref' and alternum='00'
    union all 
    select c.material,c.component,c.quantity 
    from boms b join iasbomitem c 
    on b.material=c.component)
    select * from boms;
```

But i want to list also subcodes of subcodes. I mean result shows only subcodes of topcode which is written on where clause (blue_ref). Also subcodes of LONG and SHORT must be on the list. Now result looks like

```
    select * from iasbomitem where material='blue_ref' and alternum='00'
```

but it should contain subcodes of blue_ref's subcodes.

thanks in advance...

Comment: What is the expected output for sample data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. Just have to reference the joined table in your second select.

```
with recursive boms as 
(select material,component,quantity 
from bbs604.iasbomitem 
where material='BBS81954-003-R01-KYN' 
union all 
select c.material,c.component,c.quantity 
       ^          ^           ^
from boms b join bbs604.iasbomitem c 
on b.material=c.component)
select * from boms;
```

Comment: Hi Bill, thank you for your help. but still not working after this update =( mysql workbench errors as "syntax is not correct"

Comment: Can you please run `SELECT VERSION();`? If you're not using MySQL 8.0, then CTE syntax won't work. It's a new feature in 8.0.

Comment: Oh, and I hope it's obvious I put in the `^` characters above to indicate where I made changes. Those aren't part of the query.

Comment: SELECT VERSION() = 5.5.60

Comment: so this is the reason why it's not working. thank you very much.

Comment: by the way, i found something like ; For MySQL 8+: use the recursive with syntax.
For MySQL 5.x: use inline variables, path IDs, or self-joins. I'm gonna try second option.